# How to decode JSON to record built by a data constructor?

Tags: elm

There is the type

```elm
type User
  = Anonymous
  | Named {name : String, email : String}
```

`Json.Decode.object2` doesn't fit here because its first arguments type is `(a -> b -> c)` but `Named` has `{ email : String, name : String } -> User` type.

How to decode to User?

Comment: Can you provide examples of your json that represent both an anonymous and named user?

Comment: `[{"user":null}, {"user": {"name": "John Doe", "email": "j.doe@mailg.com"}}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing this could be to define a function that accepts a name and email and returns your `Named` constructor:

```elm
userDecoder : Decoder User
userDecoder =
  let
    named =
      object2
        (\n e -> Named { name = n, email = e })
        ("name" := string)
        ("email" := string)
  in
    oneOf [ null Anonymous, named ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your `Named` constructor takes a record as a parameter, it might be a little cleaner to create a type alias for the name and email record.

```elm
type alias NamedUserInfo =
  { name : String
  , email : String
  }
```

You could then redefine `User` to use the alias:

```elm
type User
  = Anonymous
  | Named NamedUserInfo
```

While the above isn't strictly necessary, I find that aliasing record types proves useful in many ways down the road. Here it is useful because it gives us a constructor `NamedUserInfo` that lets us clearly define a decoder:

```elm
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

namedUserInfoDecoder : Decoder NamedUserInfo
namedUserInfoDecoder =
  object2
    NamedUserInfo
    ("name" := string)
    ("email" := string)
```

And finally, your user decoder could be constructed like this:

```elm
userDecoder : Decoder User
userDecoder =
  oneOf
    [ null Anonymous
    , object1 Named namedUserInfoDecoder
    ]
```

You can run your example through a quick test like this:

```elm
exampleJson =
  """
    [{"user":null}, {"user": {"name": "John Doe", "email": "j.doe@mailg.com"}}]
  """

main =
  text <| toString <| decodeString (list ("user" := userDecoder)) exampleJson

-- Ouputs:
-- Ok ([Anonymous,Named { name = "John Doe", email = "j.doe@mailg.com" }])
```

Comment: Thank you for complete answer. I'd guessed it is not possible. I'l rethink my models and will try not to use records with data constructors.